# Typolinks sometimes not generated

Tags: typo3, view-helpers, typo3-10.x, typolink

Sometimes normal links to pages are not generated by using the `typolink` viewhelper like this:

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{link}">{linktext}</f:link.typolink>
```

Without changing anything in TYPO3, but just clearing the cache, solves the problem and links are generated again without problem.

Interesting part is, that on a page only the links to one page are not generated, but other works. Example: on page 3 all links to page 4 are not generated, but to page five are working perfectly well.

This phenomenon is not reproducible, it just occurs every now and then. I can't see any errors in the TYPO3 log.

Any suggestions, how to debug?

Comment: use `<f:debug inline="1">{link}</f:debug>` in the template and check if there is no differences in links which are not rendered.

Comment: The target page is always accessible?

Comment: @JulianHofmann Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By analysing the error more in detail I found out, that it occurred because the page was requested **and cached** with the language parameter `L` attached. The value of the parameter was a language ID, which is not present in the system.

I updated the configuration in this way, that I just allow the language parameter `L` with the value `0`:

```
config.linkVars = L(0)
```

For the moment, this looks promising!